# Polling with sqlplus and logging result to a file forces in lineshifts

Tags: bash, centos, sqlplus

I am trying to make a, what I thought to be, simple bash-script that regularly polls a remote database and logs the following elements to a log-file, where only the last two elements are row-elements from the sql-query:

```
Readable timestamp, timestamp, string, Request Duration
```

Example result should look something like this:

```
Mon Sep 5 13:28:30 CEST 2016,1473074940127,text content, 4
Mon Sep 5 13:28:40 CEST 2016,1473074940127,text content, 3
Mon Sep 5 13:28:50 CEST 2016,1473074940127,text content, 2
```

The purpose of this script is to actively monitor and log response times from our local environment to the remote database, so that we can correspond errors in our local application while testing, with eventual database connection issues or similar. For this reason, we want the script to output any eventual error-messages as well. Formatting of these are not important, but we would like to see the standard output to be "comfortable" one-liners.

I have written the following quite simple script for the occasion, but it has a few eccentricities that I can't seem to remove no matter how I tune it:

```
sleep_duration=10
while true; do

SECONDS=0
timestamp="$(date),"
echo -n $timestamp >> $LOG_PATH


sqlplus -s $database << EOF >> $LOG_PATH
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode

    set echo off
    set heading off
    set linesize 1000
    set pagesize 0
    set numformat 9999999999999
    set colsep ,
    set null null

    SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1;
    exit;
EOF

echo ', '$SECONDS >> $LOG_PATH

sleep $sleep_duration
done
```

The query we send to the database always returns exactly one row with two elements, and the two elements (INTEGER, VARCHAR2) are always of the same fixed width. They can both be null if something in our application breaks locally.

I am aware of the existance of the SPOOL and TIMING commands, but have tested and opted out of using both. Spooling the query does not output any eventual surprise errors to the log-file, at least not without tricking around with error terminal outputs, so I just went with the pipe-solution in the first place. Seemed simpler. TIMING did not seem to correctly display the elapsed time of the query in the case of database downtime, so I went with the SECONDS-approach. I know this is not as precise in regards to all the sqlplus overhead that is included, but we're not interested in precise metrics anyway, we're generally just interested in seeing whether the process takes less than one second, or several minutes. Milliseconds are essentially irrelevant.

This has one big problem however, as the log ends up looking like this:

```
Mon Sep 5 14:50:47 CEST 2016, 1473079873483,text output

, 0
Mon Sep 5 14:50:57 CEST 2016, 1473079883483,text output

, 0
Mon Sep 5 14:51:07 CEST 2016, 1473079893489,text output

, 0
```

I would expect the `set pagesize 0` to remove all such trailing lineshifts from the result, but there seems to be two lineshifts after each query regardless, and I can't seem to get rid of it no matter what I try. Spooling the query gives the same results.

I considered looping inside the sqlplus-session instead, but as the script will have to run on a more or less permanent basis, I fear this would permanently reserve a connection-slot for an otherwise functionally meaningless purpose, which is undesirable. Opening and closing it as necessary seems more sensible. I have not tested this approach at all, mainly for that reason.

I am hoping to avoid having to do post-processing of the log, as I have no idea what kind of error-entries might pop up in there, so prettifying it later feels like an unneccesary regex-nightmare.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make the output cleanly line up on a single line, without unneccessary lineshifts and whitespace, while also ensuring that any eventual errors are not lost?

Comment: What is the data type of the string column - you said varchar2 but is it really that not char or clob; and how big is it; and do the string values have trailing spaces or embedded newlines?

Comment: The string value is a plain URL, field is declared as varchar2(250), and the actual length of the content is either null, or some fifty-sixty chars long. No spaces or newlines, embedded, leading or trailing - although I will triple-check there are no trailing newlines just to verify. There shouldn't be, but the URL is partially generated, so I'm not 100% certain without checking.

Comment: Can confirm, there are no spaces or newlines in the text-field at all, and the string is always exactly 36 chars wide. (Or null if something explodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a work-around, as it hasn't actually solved the lineshifts which I still haven't been able to explain, but a very simple solution to this was to simply store the sqlplus output directly to a bash variable instead of trying to print to the log from sqlplus directly, and echo it as any other variable.

Essentially, all I had to change in the script above, was wrap the sqlplus command in a variable QUERY_OUTPUT=$() and remove piping of the output:

```
while true; do

SECONDS=0
timestamp=$(date) 
echo -n "$timestamp, " >> $LOG_PATH

QUERY_RESULT=$(sqlplus -s $database << EOF
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode

    set echo off
    set heading off
    set linesize 1000
    set pagesize 0
    set numformat 9999999999999
    set colsep ', '
    set null null

    SELECT TIME, BROKER_NAME FROM ACTIVEMQ_LOCK;
    exit;
EOF
)

echo $QUERY_RESULT, $SECONDS seconds elapsed >> $LOG_PATH

sleep $sleep_duration
done
```

Stumbled across this solution on my own while spending a few hours attempting to document and verify what I had tried and not tried in the question above in the first place, and after some testing it appears to be working great. Everything is cleanly and controllably printed on one line, and any eventual errors seem to be printed cleanly on that one line as well. Spot on exactly what I were looking for.

Considered just not asking the question in the first place since I found the solution, but I figured someone else might see some value in this as well, I have not been able to find any glaringly obvious duplicates at least. Might as well share!

Comment: I don't have your system to test with, but seems like you can condense this to one line, i.e. `echo $QUERY_RESULT",$SECONDS seconds elapsed" >> $LOG_PATH` . There may be a way to get rid of extra new lines in sql processing, but this seems good enough for your purposes (But not sure why you have `'$SECONDS'`, as that will produces the literal value `$SECONDS`.) Good luck.

Comment: Aah, yes of course. It ended up on two lines essentially because I tunnel-visioned on it being two "problems" I think. Will edit with that!

Comment: As for the ticked-in SECONDS bit, the ticks aren't wrapping the seconds, but the leading and trailing text. I'm not a native bash-savvy veteran, so I didn't even realize they were unneccessary, hehe. Will test it quickly, and edit with a fix for both! 

Would be cool if someone saw an immediate trick to getting rid of the trailing newlines as well though yeah, my workaround suits me perfectly in this particular situation, but that's not necessarily always the case I expect.